# Using Geopandas and Scipy.interpolate, how can I only display the interpolated map and exclude the grid?

Tags: python, geopandas, scipy

I am using `scipy.interpolate` to interpolate a dataset to within a boundary. I need to know how to display only the interpolated data without grid overlay, just to clean up the display. In other words, even though I use a grid to interpolate across the entire field, I need to display it without the grid. How can I do that?

For reproducibility, the data can be found and downloaded from [this Google drive directory](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f2te3k4UtLUHC4padNHgdDnzwO5O0fm8?usp=sharing). You will need both the .csv file and the .shp file. The .csv file is 7KB, whereas the shape files total up to 22KB.

Here is what I have tried:

```
# Import modules
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import box
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Read in data
df = pd.read_csv('python_question.csv')
bnd = gpd.read_file('bound.shp')

# Reproject shapefile boundary
bnd  = bnd.to_crs("epsg:4326")

# Convert DataFrame to GeoDataFrame
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
df.head()

# Define coordinate systems
epsg_wgs = 4326 # World Geodetic System 1984
epsg_utm = 32614 # UTM Zone 14

# Convert latitude and longitude to point data
df['geometry'] = gpd.points_from_xy(df['Longitude'], 
                                     df['Latitude'],
                                    crs = epsg_wgs)

df.head()

# Check CRS for both datasets
print(bnd.crs)
print(df.crs)


# Plotting of map boundary and sampled points
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
bnd.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
df.plot(ax=ax, marker='x', facecolor='k')
plt.show()


# Find and delete points outside of the field boundaries
print(df.shape)
for k,row in df.iterrows(): #Prints row without indexed rows
    point = row['geometry']
    if not point.within(bnd['geometry'].iloc[0]):
        df.drop(k, inplace=True) #Drops the Kth row
        
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print(df.shape)


# Plot again after deleting the points outside of the boundary
# Plotting of map boundary and sampled points
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
bnd.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
df.plot(ax=ax, marker='x', facecolor='k')
plt.show()


# Create grid to interpolate over
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = bnd.to_crs(epsg=epsg_utm).total_bounds #Represents field in terms of meters

# Define cell size
xdelta = 1 # meters
ydelta = 1 # meters

# Create an empty array to save the grid
grid = np.array([])

for x in np.arange(xmin, xmax, xdelta): #min, max step
    for y in np.arange(ymin, ymax, ydelta): #min, max step
        cell = box(x,y, x+xdelta, y+ydelta)
        grid = np.append(grid, cell)
        
gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid, columns=['geometry'], crs=epsg_utm)
gdf_grid['centroids'] = gdf_grid['geometry'].centroid
gdf_grid.head()

# Convert CRS back to Lat/Long
gdf_grid['geometry'] = gdf_grid['geometry'].to_crs(crs=epsg_wgs)
gdf_grid['centroids'] = gdf_grid['centroids'].to_crs(crs=epsg_wgs)


# Plot field boundaries, points, and grid
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
bnd.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='r')
df.plot(ax=ax, marker='x', facecolor='k')
gdf_grid.plot(ax=ax, facecolor = 'None', edgecolor='k')
plt.show()



# Clip cells to shapefile boundary
gdf_grid = gpd.clip(gdf_grid, bnd['geometry'].iloc[0])
gdf_grid.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

#Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
bnd.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='r')
df.plot(ax=ax, marker='x', facecolor='k')
gdf_grid.plot(ax=ax, facecolor = 'None', edgecolor='k')
plt.show()


# Interpolate the values of observed automobiles to each centroid
x = df['geometry'].x
y = df['geometry'].y
z = df['car_obs']

xq = gdf_grid['centroids'].x
yq = gdf_grid['centroids'].y

# Arrange variables in griddata input format
points = (x,y)
values = z
xi = (xq, yq)

car_nn = griddata(points,
                    values,
                    xi,
                    method='nearest')

#Save interpolated data values into the geodataframe
gdf_grid['car_obs'] = car_nn.round(1)


# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
bnd.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='w', edgecolor='r')
gdf_grid.plot(ax=ax, column='car_obs', edgecolor='k', cmap='OrRd')
plt.show()
```

The plot looks like the image below. I just need to plot the interpolations without the grid on top of it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying `edgecolor='k'` you are telling geopandas/matplotlib to draw the grid borders.

You can set `edgecolor='none'` to turn the borders off, but you still get some white lines as a result of [antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774835/737471):

[image]

To get rid of those white lines, set `edgecolor="face", linewidth=0.5` or `edgecolor="none", antialiased=False`.

Note in the example below, I also plot `bnd` after `gdf_grid` and set `facecolor='none'` so the boundary draws on top, otherwise the borders get masked a bit by the grid.

```py
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(8,8))
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
gdf_grid.plot(ax=ax, column='car_obs', cmap='OrRd', edgecolor="none", antialiased=False)
# gdf_grid.plot(ax=ax, column='car_obs', cmap='OrRd', edgecolor="face", linewidth=0.5)
bnd.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]